# Insert Tuple of Tuples Into Snowflake Table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

Insert tuple of tuples into Snowflake Table. I am using Python with the Snowpark connector. The Data is stored in a tuple of tuples like this:

```
data = ((1,"CA"),(2, "NY"), (3, "TX"))
```

I'm doing something like this, but this does not work:

```
session.sql(f"""INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, CITY) VALUES {data}""").collect()
```

Table has two columns, ID and City. I want to insert data into the table in one statement. Variable data could have more than 3 tuples in the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use parametrized query

```
from snowflake import connector
connector.paramstyle='qmark'
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='<user>',
    account='<account_identifier>',
    private_key=pkb,
    warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
    database=DATABASE,
    schema=SCHEMA
    )

cs = ctx.cursor()
data = ((1,"CA"),(2, "NY"), (3, "TX"))
stmt2 = "INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, CITY) values (?, ?)"
cs.executemany(stmt2, data)
```

Comment: Yeah that would work, but not in my case, since I am using the Snowpark connector.